# Flask: Keeping original file upload on form update instead of removing the image?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

My problem is that I am trying to keep the original file that has been uploaded on form update, I have it working that if the file is updated, it updates, but if the field is left blank, the file is then blank rather than simply remaining as the original image.

I have tried to add the value `value="{{ book.book_cover_photo }}"` to the form input and pass it in as a request.form.get in hopes that the original filename would be saved, but it still returns blank.

I have also tried using an if statement to distinguish between if the filename is empty or not, and if it is leaving it out of the update completely, but this also didnt work and the image was removed from the post.

```py
if 'book_cover_photo' in request.files:
    book_cover_photo = request.files['book_cover_photo']
    if book_cover_photo.filename != '':
        mongo.save_file(secure_filename(book_cover_photo.filename), book_cover_photo)

        books = mongo.db.books
        books.update({'_id' : ObjectId(book_id)},
        {
            'book_name' : request.form.get('book_name'),
            'book_cover_photo' : book_cover_photo.filename,
        })
    else:
        books = mongo.db.books
        books.update({'_id' : ObjectId(book_id)},
        {
            'book_name' : request.form.get('book_name'),
        })

return redirect(url_for('get_books'))
```

I am not getting any error messages, it updates just fine, the only issue being it overrides so when I refresh my URL is simply /uploads/ rather than /uploads/filename.extension

Comment: what is the value of `book_cover_photo.filename` when file is not uploaded?

Comment: I would expect if it's not being updated (i.e.  if I leave it out of the else statement) then it would  remain as it was set in the original upload, if I put into the template of the update form `value="{{ book.book_cover_photo }}"` i get the correct value, but this seems to do nothing, as if I update with this, I still end up with a blank image

Comment: It always seems to be defaulting to null on update unless a new image is uploaded

Comment: In that case check for null value not empty string

Comment: It's returning null in mongo but not in Python, if I change the empty string to None it completely skips and falls to my backup return

Comment: Is it possible for me to use something like `this` in mongo? In which case if its empty I can use my function to retrieve e.g. this.book_cover_photo rather than request.form.get('book_cover_photo')?

Comment: Ok, as I see it's literally completely overriding everything (if I remove it, then it's removed from the db hence its empty, and if it's there and the field is empty it's set to null) so I need to figure out a way to only update the field if it's changed. I'll peruse the docs.